# Laravel: Is this a good practice to put all my code inside DB transaction? Even none DB query codes?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions

I am creating a subscribing and teaming! system.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
    $sub = Sub::create($sub_data);

    if(request for new team){
       $team = Team:create($team_data)
       Mail::queue....// sending email and notif
       // some php code here
    }
    elseif(request to join a team) 
    {
       $team = Team:find($team_data)
       $team->subscriber()->create($team_data) // a team has many subscribers
       Mail::queue....// sending email and notif
       // some php code here
    }
     // Here some extra queries...
```

Now I want all queries to be executed in a DB transaction.  can I put all the above code in Laravel Transaction closure?

```
DB::transaction(function()
{
 // all the above code here 
});
```

I mean having so many php code and none Query logic, like sending Email... Is this a good practice? If it isn't, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acording to Laravel docs:

> You may use the transaction method on the DB facade to run a set of operations within a database transaction. If an exception is thrown within the transaction Closure, the transaction will automatically be rolled back. If the Closure executes successfully, the transaction will automatically be committed.

You use transactions when the set of database operations you are making needs to be atomic.

That is - they all need to succeed or fail. Nothing in between.

Transactions are to be used to ensure that the database is always in a consistent state.

**Is a bad practice to create a transaction always?**

It depends on what context you are talking here. If it is an update, then I would highly recommend using TRANSACTIONS explicitly. If it is a SELECT then NO (explicitly).

Comment: Yes I want all queries to be done OR  none of them!  So there is no problem to have so many logic in transaction closure. right? (so many if's switch case! and php logic not query...)   what do you mean: using TRANSACTIONS explicitly ?

Comment: Explicitly means clear and detailed. So if you want all queries to success or in case of fail rollback everything, you must use transactions.

Comment: What i dont recommend is selecting in transactions because when you use transaction the table goes in something like "pause" mode and no other queries run until the transaction is made. we can say that the database loose the async functionality while the transaction is running

Comment: I know the meaning of Explicitly! :)) Thank you I get it.  So if I don't want my queries to rollback when for example  `Send Email Exception`  happens, I have to refactor my code and put email logic outside transaction. The rest of the code could remain inside except `Select` queries for performance issues...